# How to continue with the same stream when a node is a rejected promise?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using `redux-observable` in order to dispatch an action with a transformation of some promise result.

Let's say I have an API call like this:

```
const fetchSomething = () => callAndReturnPromise('some-endpoint')
```

Using these action creators:

```
const fetchSomethingSuccess = response => ({ type: 'SUCCESS', payload: response })
const fetchSomethingError = error => ({ type: 'ERROR', payload: error })
```

I can create actions for both cases, when `fetchSomething` is resolved or rejected.

I want my epic to take all 'FETCH' actions and use the `fetchSomething` function to put a new node with the resolved or rejected value of the promise using the proper action creators.

My epic is looking like this:

```
const fetchSomethingEpic = action$ =>
    action$
        .ofType('FETCH')
        .switchMap(() => 
            Observable
                .fromPromise(fetchSomething())
                .map(fetchSomethingSuccess)
                .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchSomethingError(error)))
    );
```

The problem is that it stops working when an error occurs.

When the promise generated by `fetchSomething` is being resolved, everything just goes fine, a new action is dispatched with the transformation passed with map. But when the the promise is rejected, no action is dispatched after the 'FETCH'

--

More info

The `callAndReturnPromise('some-endpoint)` looks like this:

```
const callAndReturnPromise = endpoint => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response => {
            if (checkIsCool(response)) {
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(response)
            }
    })
})
```

After debugging I get something like this, let's name the actions in the stream with F, S, E (fetch, success and error)

```
----F----S------F-------F------S
                     ^ there occurred an error but no action was sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that it stops working when an error occurs

Can you be more specific? What exactly stops working and how do you know? Are there any errors? etc.

---

I do see a problem right away, but it would have been a parse error so it's likely just a typo in your question: returning an Object from an arrow function requires wrapping the curly braces in parenthesis.

```
// before
const fetchSomethingSuccess = response => { type: 'SUCCESS', payload: response }
const fetchSomethingError = error => { type: 'ERROR', payload: error }

// after
const fetchSomethingSuccess = response => ({ type: 'SUCCESS', payload: response })
const fetchSomethingError = error => ({ type: 'ERROR', payload: error })
```

While in this specific case it would have been a parse error, there are cases where it would silently actually parse as a block with a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) which is extremely confusing for many.

e.g. this is totally valid JavaScript and is not a parse error:

```
const fetchSomethingSuccess = response => { type: 'SUCCESS' }
```

In this case, `{ type: 'SUCCESS' }` is a block with an extraneous labeled statement of a string, both of which are not used or returned in any way. Think of it functionally equivalent to this:

```
const fetchSomethingSuccess = function (response) {
  type: 'SUCCESS'; // extraneous
  // no return
};
```

---

Based on our further conversations and the new provided code:

I added the provided code into a jsbin and it seems to work as I'd expect, the `ERROR` action is dispatched correctly. https://jsbin.com/rujemak/edit?js,output

Comment: I am sorry, it was just a typo, let me fix it I just updated the answer explaining what's happening. I don't know if it is because the catch is inside the switchMap.

Comment: @cnexans sorry man still not clear. No action is dispatched when the promise is rejected but is there any errors in the console? What have you tried to debug? Your code actually looks correct AFAICT, so have you tried standard debugging stuff like Pause on Caught Exception, .do({ error: callback }) stuff, etc

Comment: Is your code 100% identical to the example? otherwise there may be subtle things missing from your example perhaps.

Comment: I'll add couple more information in the question, thank you very much!

Comment: I think it is because when it promise is rejected, the switchMap stops the subscription for some reason

Comment: @cnexans when you wrap a promise with `fromPromise` if the promise rejects it goes down the Observable error path, which the `catch` would...catch.

Comment: @cnexans updated my answer, I added your code to a jsbin and it works as I'd expect https://jsbin.com/rujemak/edit?js,output